# python methods with no implementation

Tags: python, methods

Is this the correct way to definel methods with no implementation. A suggestion or a link that would help me would be appreciated. My code works fine but am I doing it right?

```
class BankAccount(object):
    @staticmethod
    def withdraw():
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def deposit():
        pass
```

Comment: withdraw and deposit will certainly need access to the state of a BankAccount, so they should not be staticmethods.

Comment: And alternative to the `pass` would be to `raise` a `NotImplementedError` to make sure not to run methods that have not been implemented.

Comment: @wim will make a correction on that

Comment: You are not calling any methods there.  You're only defining them.

Comment: that sounds more effective than pass. Thanks

Comment: Not entirely sure that's what you want but there are "official" [abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html?highlight=abc#module-abc) in the standard lib.

Comment: @BrenBarn i meant define. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Surely you those methods have implementations, it's just that they do nothing?

Comment: @PaulRooney They do nothing which is what i want. How do you define methods with  no implementation was my question

Comment: for anyone interested i found a link thanks@KlausD. [link](https://dwieeb.com/2015/06/02/usages-of-notimplemented-and-notimplementederror-in-python/)